# Run a VS Python module from a VS C++ application

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I am trying to run a VS Python application module from a VS C++ application.

I have the following snippet.  I have a value for pName but get a NULL for pModule.

```
pName = PyUnicode_FromString("C:\\PythonApplication2.py");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
```

The python application runs fine in the python env.  Is there a tutorial or example that will get me past this issue?

Here is the c++ code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pArgs, * pValue;
Py_Initialize();
pName = PyUnicode_FromString("C:<name of python file>.py");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "multiply");

Py_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: I suspect we're going to need a few more lines.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a setting that I have missed or the python lib.  I am using Python 3.7.9.  The code compiles but the PyImport always returns a NULL.